# Test a controller in .Net Core always returns false?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

I write the following XUnit test to test a .Net Core WebApi controller's action:

```
namespace VistaBest.XUnitTest.Api.Test
{
    public class Account_UnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ValidateUserTest()
        {
            const string username = "admin";
            const string password = "admin";
            var usersBusinessObjectMock = new Mock<IUsersBusinessObject>();
            usersBusinessObjectMock.Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(username, password)).Returns(() => true);
            var controller = new AccountController(usersBusinessObjectMock.Object);
            var actionResult = controller.ValidateUser(new LoginModel
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            });
            var okObjectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult);
            var result = okObjectResult.Value as bool?;
            Assert.True(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountController**:

```
namespace VistaBest.Api.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IUsersBusinessObject _usersBusinessObject;
        public AccountController(IUsersBusinessObject usersBusinessObject)
        {
            _usersBusinessObject = usersBusinessObject;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ValidateUser(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
            return Ok(_usersBusinessObject.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password.ToMd5Hash()));
        }
    }
}
```

**IUsersBusinessObject**:

```
namespace VistaBest.Data.BusinessObjects
{
    public interface IUsersBusinessObject
    {
        bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
        UserModel SelectByUsername(string username);
    }

    public class UsersBusinessObject : BaseBusinessObject, IUsersBusinessObject
    {
        public UsersBusinessObject(IDbConnection connection) : base(connection)
        {

        }

        private const string TableName = "Users";

        public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            var query = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{TableName}] WHERE UserName = @username and Password = @password";
            return DbConnection.QueryFirst<int>(query, new { username, password }) == 1;
        }
}
```

As you see I said `usersBusinessObjectMock` must return `true`:

```
usersBusinessObjectMock
    .Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(username, password))
    .Returns(() => true);
```

But `var result = okObjectResult.Value as bool?;` is always `false`

What's wrong?

[image: Test Error Screen Shot]

Comment: What happens if you just cast the value to a boolean ie `var result = (bool) okObjectResult.Value;`

Comment: @Nkosi: result is always false, see watch section in the image in main post

Comment: We were focusing on the wrong thing. The mock was not configured correctly and thus was not behaving as expected. Check my provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rechecking how the controller calls the validation method I realized that  the problem is that you are not configuring the mock correctly.

The controller is calling

```
_usersBusinessObject.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password.ToMd5Hash())
```

Note the `ToMd5Hash()` being called on the password.

You however setup the mock like...

```
usersBusinessObjectMock
    .Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(username, password))
    .Returns(() => true);
```

See the problem?

The mock is expecting the raw password and not its hash, thus wont return `true` when passed the hashed password. This results in the action's object result always returning `false` because the mock always returns `false`. That method was hidden off screen so I did not notice it earlier.

So assuming `ToMd5Hash()` is some custom extension method,

you either setup the mock to expect the hashed password to match the method under test...

```
usersBusinessObjectMock
    .Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(username, password.ToMd5Hash()))
    .Returns(() => true);
```

or use the `It.IsAny<>()` methods to loosen the expectations of the mock...

```
usersBusinessObjectMock
    .Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() => true);
```

so that is does not matter what values you pass to the mock, it will always return `true`

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

After reading your code like 10 minutes, as this error is really hard to find. You did everything right...

```
        var okObjectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult);
        var result = okObjectResult.Value as bool?;
        Assert.True(result);
```

But here is the error...

var is dangerous...
your variable okObjectResult is not from type OkObjectResult... that's why your assert is never true...
Im sure you mean't to type

```
Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult);
var okObjectResult = (OkObjectResult) actionResult;
```

Comment: Do note that [Assert.IsType(T)](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/xunit.extensions/xunit.extensions/Assertions/M/IsType(T)) is suppose to cast the provided object to the provided type.

Comment: I change my code like you write, nothing change and okObjectResult Value is always false !

Answer (score 3):

This will work and I make some small refactor in your code.

```
namespace VistaBest.XUnitTest.Api.Test
{
  public class Account_UnitTest
  {
    private readonly Mock<IUsersBusinessObject> _usersBusinessObjectMock;
    private readonly AccountController _accountController;
    public Account_UnitTest() 
    {
       _usersBusinessObjectMock = new Mock<IUsersBusinessObject>();
       _accountController = new AccountController(_usersBusinessObjectMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ValidateUserTest()
    {
        var model = new LoginModel
        {
            Username = "admin",
            Password = "admin"
        };

        _usersBusinessObjectMock.Setup(service => service.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)).Returns(() => true);

        var actual = _accountController.ValidateUser(model) as OkObjectResult;

        actual.Value.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(true); 
        // or Assert.True(actual.Value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I change my code like you write, nothing change and `actual.Value` is always false !